# Getting factory not registered (ArgumentError) when trying to run test with rspec and factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I keep getting `Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)`
when I try to run my test files with `factory_girl_rails`. I read several post about that and tried to follow each of them without any success. In my gemfile I have the `gem 'factory_girl_rails'`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I have a spec folder in my project with different folders inside :
controllers, factories, models, lib and support. 
In my spec folder I have a `spec_helper.rb` :

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
 end
```

and a rails_helper.rb :

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
    # Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
    abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
    require 'spec_helper'
    require 'rspec/rails'
    require 'devise'
    require_relative 'support/controller_macros'
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Inside my factories' folder, I have files for each one of my models for instance tournaments.rb :

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tournament do |f|
    f.user FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    f.accepted [true, false].sample
    f.amount  { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    f.starts_on { Faker::Date.between(2.days.ago, Date.today) }
    f.ends_on { Faker::Date.forward(23) }
    f.address {Faker::Address.street_address}
    f.city { Faker::Address.city }
    f.name { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    f.club_organisateur { Faker::Company.name }
    f.homologation_number {Faker::Company.swedish_organisation_number}
    f.postcode { Faker::Address.postcode }
    f.young_fare { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    f.iban "jjddjjdjdjdjddj"
    f.bic "djdjdjdjdjdjdjdjd"
    f.club_email { Faker::Internet.email }
    f.region "Ile de France"
  end
end
```

Inside controllers folder, I have for instance `tournaments_controller_spec.rb` that looks like this :

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'spec_helper'



describe TournamentsController do
  render_views
  login_user

  describe "index" do
    it "returns a valid html_body"  do
      get :index
      expect(response.body).to include("Il n'y a pas encore de tournoi référencé sur WeTennis")
    end
  end

  describe "show" do
    it "returns a valid tournament si le tournament n'est pas fini" do
      get :show
      expect(response.body).to include("s'inscrire")
    end
  end
end
```

and inside models folder for instance tournament_spec.rb :

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Tournament do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:tournament).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a start date"  do
    FactoryGirl.build(:tournament, start_date: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a end date"  do
    FactoryGirl.build(:tournament, end_date: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a user"  do
    FactoryGirl.build(:tournament, user: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

My users factory looks exactly like the others in folder factories (users.rb)
require 'factory_girl_rails'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name}
    f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    f.password { Faker::Internet.password}
    f.licence_number { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    f.email  { Faker::Internet.email }
  end
end
```

same for my user_spec.rb inside my models folder :

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without an email"  do
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a password"  do
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Well, do you have a `:user` factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is your use of the user factory in the tournament factory (and maybe others):

```
factory :tournament do |f|
  f.user FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

FactoryGirl allows you to created associated objects quite simply (see [the relevant section their documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)). To add an associated object which is created by a factory you can just do:

```
  f.user
```

This will cause FactoryGirl to create a user object using the equivalent of `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` when a tournament is created.

Note also that you don't need the `f.` prefix. It should work find without.

The reason that it is causing an error is that the code `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` is being executed when your tournament factory loads and the user factory hasn't been loaded at that point. For stuff like: `region 'Ile de France` it doesn't matter because the string can be evaluated fine but for another factory call it does matter because the factory has to be defined already.